# dnsmasq cache NOERROR with ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0

Tags: domain-name-system, dnsmasq

I use a public DNS provider (nextdns.io) that blocks some domains. These blocked domains return a response like this when `dig`-ed:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> example.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 63541
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.               IN      A

;; Query time: 66 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Jul 22 12:03:25 CDT 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 33
```

I use dnsmasq on a DD-WRT router to handle all DNS queries from devices on the local network. Is there a way to configure dnsmasq to cache these `NOERROR` results with 0 `ANSWER`/`AUTHORITY`?

Viewing logs, I can tell that my upstream DNS provider continues to get hammered by a client on my network trying to access some blocked domains frequently.

I explored the dnsmasq manpage, but the cache/ttl flags I see do not seem to have an effect on these types of responses since they are not negative (e.g. `NXDOMAIN`) cacheable but are just no answer at all. I know that I could explicitly handle certain domains in my dnsmasq config by adding records like `address=/.example.com/::`, but I'd prefer to add a cache/ttl at my dnsmasq to cache no answers for something like 300 seconds before trying to query for an answer from upstream again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem in terms of caching is that this some form of a broken response (I would think broken `NODATA` based on the suggested intent).

DNS caching is done based on some TTL, for positive responses the RRSet TTL and for negative responses the cache TTL is based on the `SOA` record in the `AUTHORITY` section (specifically the TTL used is `MIN(SOA TTL, SOA.MINIMUM)`).

Whether a negative response is `NXDOMAIN` or `NODATA` (`NOERROR` with empty `ANSWER`), these response types always have the relevant `SOA` record in the `AUTHORITY` section.

It would of course be better if the filtering DNS provider would serve valid responses also for filtered domains (ie, a proper `NXDOMAIN` or `NODATA` response).

Working around the problem is not necessarily straightforward as this is not a type of response that is supposed to exist, and there is not necessarily an option to catch this case.

However, you are using `dnsmasq`, which according to the [dnsmasq manual](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html) has a setting which would appear to deal with this situation:

> **`--neg-ttl=<time>`**
> Negative replies from upstream servers normally contain time-to-live information in SOA records which dnsmasq uses for
> caching. If the replies from upstream servers omit this information,
> dnsmasq does not cache the reply. This option gives a default value
> for time-to-live (in seconds) which dnsmasq uses to cache negative
> replies even in the absence of an SOA record.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful information. I had tried using `neg-ttl=300`, however, but it didn't seem to have an effect. I may need to open a ticket to the DNS provider (nextdns.io) to see about changing their response to blocked domains. I see that pi-hole, a similar service, [returns NXDOMAIN or NODATA](https://docs.pi-hole.net/ftldns/blockingmode/#pi-holes-nxdomain-blocking).

Comment: @CollinM.Barrett Ok, interesting. Maybe it doesn't recognize the "partial `NODATA`" as a case where it can apply `neg-ttl`, then. Maybe it works with "partial `NXDOMAIN`" only.